# source map not showing the files source webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack

In my webpack config i have this these under `module.exports`,

```
devtool: '#source-map',
debug: true,
```

[image: result]

But as from the screenshot it does not generate the source files, there is not even the `webpack://`. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the hash from the attribute

```
devtool: 'source-map',
```

Also the docs might help you select the best type of source map to use.  I personally don't use source-map I like the inline source maps. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Also see. https://survivejs.com/webpack/building/source-maps/

Comment: removed the hash, tried inline source maps aswell but still no output. Any thoughts ?